# Following Google's Android tuto, message value passed to putExtra does not find symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying my hand with Android dev by following Google's developer website and training. Now I am stuck at a very basic point:

On this page:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

Google mentions you need to add extra information (the message) to the Intent by adding the text previously entered in the input field. However after following the instructions Android Studio doesn't seem to agree:

[image]

I've been trying to figure out for ages what's wrong with the value that I pass to putExtra(), can't seem to get it :(

Any help?

Comment: Use `editText.getText().toString()` instead of `message`

Comment: I'd love to try that, thanks! Would you mind explaining a little bit more so I can try to understand what is wrong and how this solution solves the problem?

Comment: Sure, see in provided link you are missing one line in code before `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);` which is `String message = editText.getText().toString();` in this line `message` is a String and `editText.getText()` return data input by user in EditText

Comment: Ok so I just went too fast and forgot a line, damn it! I feel silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the text to a local `String` Type message variable, and use the `putExtra()` method to add its text value to the `intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

Comment: Ok my bad, I guess I went too fast then and forgot the line. Silly!